# How do I search for a certain piece of text inside of a variable?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am working on a script which prompts the user for their username. Once entered, the script uses the 'rwho' command to get a list of users who are logged into the network. It should crosscheck the text they entered (their username) with the results from the rwho command.

If a match is found then it displays a message saying so, if not then it also makes the user aware of this.

Here is the script and my attempt so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# User network checking script
#

# Using rwho command to get user list
OUTPUT="$(rwho)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"

# Prompt for username
echo "Please enter your username: " 
read username

# Input validation
if [ -z "$username"]
  then
   echo "No username supplied"
   echo "Please enter your username: "
 read username
fi

# Search for user
if `echo ${OUTPUT} | grep "${username}" 1>/dev/null 2>&1'
 then 
   echo "$username is logged in."
 else
   echo "$username is not present."  
fi
```

I consistently get errors with the Search for User part. I don't have outstanding knowledge of Linux so if anyone could fix this and help me I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: You get "errors" do you? Perhaps you should show them to us? Also check your syntax you are missing a closing `\`` on the `grep` pipeline. Also use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get general helpful suggestions for your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of quotes is weird.

```
if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "$username"
```

should work.

`-q` makes `grep` quiet (and is shorter than your redirections).

Comment: Because as-written the original code runs the `echo | grep` pipeline and then *tries to run its output* as a command (because of the wrapping backticks).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Well, there's no closing backquote, in fact, but there's a single quote that probably should have been the backquote.

Comment: Right. I assumed the backticks were intentional and miswritten.